# Which RTOS synchronization method shall I use for waiting until all tasks are initialized?

Tags: synchronization, freertos

I have a lot of tasks in my application. Some tasks depend on others.

For example I have console task that prints outputs from all other "worker" tasks, so all these tasks before printing anything must wait until console task is fully initialized.

I have also more dependencies like this, with kind of dependency tree structure. For example task_modbus needs 3 tasks to be initialized: task_uart, task_filesystem, task_console.

What kind of synchronization object shall I use?

At this moment I'm using semaphores, one for each task dependency relation.

**I was thinking about EventGroup, but maybe there is something more lightweight?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [xEventGroupSync](https://www.freertos.org/xEventGroupSync.html)() API seems most appropriate.